# Only 1 out of 5 mysql statements run when executed php do

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My statements are prepared like this:

```
$statement_1 = $DBH->prepare("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_1`;
    CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
        ... statements are all running fine in phpmyadmin when executed separately
");
$statement_2 = $DBH->prepare("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_2`;
    CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
        ... statements are all running fine in phpmyadmin when executed separately
");
$statement_3 = $DBH->prepare("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_3`;
    CREATE TABLE `table_3` (
        ... statements are all running fine in phpmyadmin when executed separately
");
$statement_4 = $DBH->prepare("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_4`;
    CREATE TABLE `table_4` (
        ... statements are all running fine in phpmyadmin when executed separately
");
$statement_5 = $DBH->prepare("
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_5`;
    CREATE TABLE `table_5` (
        ... statements are all running fine in phpmyadmin when executed separately
");
```

Then I try and execute the statements in separate if statements so that I can see that all the statements were executed successfully, like so:

```
if($statement_1->execute()){
    echo "statement_1 executed successfully!";
}else{
    echo "statement_1 failed to execute!";
}

if($statement_2->execute()){
    echo "statement_2 executed successfully!";
}else{
    echo "statement_2 failed to execute!";
}
....
```

.. and so on and so on for the rest of the statements.

My issue is when I try to run all the statements in the ifs, only the first statement runs (statement_1). The rest are unsuccessful.

Do I need to run all the statements as one long string? Or in a transaction block?

Comment: May I ask the need for a prepare for what I think is an db installation script? Why not use `query()` directly?

Comment: Call `$statement2->errorInfo()` in the else section of `$statement2` to know what's wrong. You should call the same method in the other else statements too.

Comment: Hey Eduardo, it just says "Array" after my usual message

Comment: try var_dump($statement2->errorInfo());

Comment: Hi marcellorvalle, I get the following: "array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "HY000" [1]=> int(2014) [2]=> string(269) "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute." }"

Comment: @Xorifelse, how would I execute the statements using query() instead of prepare()? (sorry I know off topic)

Comment: Seems you need to close the last statment before executing the next.

Comment: You aren't preparing anything. swap the word prepare for query, get rid of the execute lines.. and you're done.

Comment: @Farkie, makes sense but I'm getting irregular results now, 1 executes, 2 doesn't, 3 executes, 4 doesn't and 5 doesn't. Weird, I'll look for errors in my sql syntax ;)

Comment: you need to close it...  `$statement_1->closeCursor()` in each successfull part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the statement when you're done with it...

```
if($statement_1->execute()){
    $statement_1->closeCursor();
    echo "statement_1 executed successfully!";
}else{
    echo "statement_1 failed to execute!";
}

if($statement_2->execute()){
    $statement_2->closeCursor();
    echo "statement_2 executed successfully!";
}else{
    echo "statement_2 failed to execute!";
}
```

Good luck